# How do I validate a string to be a date in the format dd-M-y, and not be a past date?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a date field and the format is "dd-M-y", example 01-Jan-2013. First I want to check the format which must be "dd-M-y" and secondly the date shouldn't be in the past but can be today and onward.

How would I do that? I would like to use regular expressions but I don't know what a suitable one would be.

Comment: I think it's better to convert it to a `DateTime` object first. It would make date manipulation and validation easier and more robust.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` rather than using Regex to validate your DateTime

```
string testDate = "01-Jan-2013";
DateTime temp;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(testDate, 
                           "dd-MMM-yyyy", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, 
                           out temp) &&
    (temp > DateTime.Today))
{
    //Valid date and greater than today
}
else
{
    //Invalid date or less than today
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind the user to fill the date in correct format instead of checking for it...

The Best solution in this case would be [MaskEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)